# Importação de dados JSON entre arquivos Python

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver

eu estou com uma dificuldade.

eu tenho um código em selenium(teste.py) e eu tenho outro código python de filas(queue.py)
meu objetivo é passar a mensagem de erro [ error = {'Status': 'Error'} ] para o resultdo(queue.py)

### teste.py

```
    def run():
        try:
          driver = webdriver.Firefox()
          driver.get('https://www.google.com')
          elem =  driver.find_element_by_name('q')
          elem.send_keys()    
          elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        except:
            error = {'Status': 'Error'} 
            dados = json.loads(error)
```

### queue.py

*é só um pedaço do código.*

```
    import pika
    import json
    def worker(ch, method, properties, body):
        print("\tBody: %r" % body)
        try:
            data = json.loads(body)
            print(data['nome'])
            import teste

    result{
         "Status_de_error" : dados['Status'] 
      }
```

mas o o arquivo (queue.py) me retorna o seguinte erro.

> global name 'dados' is not defined

*obs : os dois arquivos estão na mesma pasta*

alguém pode me ajudar por favor???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na parte `import teste` nada ocorrerá pois sua função run() não foi chamada. Você pode fazer assim:

```
    from teste import run
    teste.run()
```